# Group by segments then within each group split into unique batches - SQL Challenge

Tags: sql

I have a table with duplicate email addresses. This is where contacts have a shared (duplicate) email address. This table has various segments and I want to group all records together for each segment, then within each segment split the records into unique batches, so that each batch doesn't have a duplicate email address in them. Therefore for each segment I need a query that would need to generate enough batches until there was no more duplicate email addresses.

There's circa 20,000 records and i need a way to generate an output that will give us each segement split into batches that only have unique email addresses.

Comment: welcome. some sample data would help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select row_number() over (partition by email order by email) as batchnum,
       t.*
from t;
```

The first column is a batch number.  Rows with the same batch number are guaranteed to have unique emails.